# issue with image update in yii.2.0

Tags: yii2

I am a newbie php developer. Working in yii2.0 framework !!. I have a form to create new record and update the existing form. My problem is I file input field to upload an image in the form. Upload new image and update old image is working fine, but I want it as, If the user doesn't upload new image while updating , the old image itself should be saved ,how should I do that? please help me, Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is my actionUpdate function in the controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    { 
        $imageInstance = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'Image');
        $randm = rand(278, 99999);
        $fileName = "{$randm}-{$imageInstance}";
        $model->Image = $fileName;
        $userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->userId;
        $restaurantId = \app\models\Restaurantbusiness::findOne(['userId' =>
        $userId])->restaurentID;
        $model->restaurantBusiness_restaurentID = $restaurantId;
        $model->delFlg = 0;
        $model->createdDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $model->modifiedDate = date('Y-m-d');
        if($model->save()) 
        {
            $imageInstance->saveAs('../uploads/' . $fileName);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->menuId]);
        }else
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            ]); 
        }
    }else
        {
            return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: you can check for new record just like create or update buttons. for ex. $model->isNewRecord? create:update

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check if the image field is empty or not.

A basic example is to use php Ternary Operator
documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Create a variable called image which contains the image you have in the db if $imageInstance is empty else it get the uploaded image

```
$image = (empty($imageInstance))? $model->Image : $fileName ;
```

Then you assign the variable to your model

```
$model->Image = $image;
```

Comment: thank you for replying to me sir :),where should i write this code?? after $model->Image = $fileName; ?

Comment: could you please rewrite the code to me .. !! i am not getting where to add the above code :(

Comment: the code should be put after $fileName and before $model->Image

Comment: i am getting this error "Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object"

Comment: its not working, actually i am not getting any value in $image after submitting the form without choosing any image

Comment: it gives you NULL if there isn't any image stored in your db or you don't select any image to upload

Comment: thanks i solved it :) , i stored that image in one variable but the data is getting submitted n used that variable in else condition to store the old image in the database :) , thanks grischer , n thanks Awesome AP for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Controller*/ 
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if($image){
                $model->image = $image;
                
                if ($model->upload()) {
                    $model->image = Url::base(true).'uploads/'.$image->name;
                    
                    if ($model->update(false)) {
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }           
                }    
            }else {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
            }
        }

/*Model*/
public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->image->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value from the table temporarily to a variable, then return the previous value if no new upload.

```
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $imgTempName = $model->image;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    { 
        $imageInstance = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'Image');
        if($imageInstance && $imageInstance->size>0){
           $randm = rand(278, 99999);
           $fileName = "{$randm}-{$imageInstance}";
           $model->Image = $fileName;
     }else{
           $model->image = $imgTempName;
     }
```